# Alter URL prefix for Wicket resource URLs?

Tags: java, url, servlets, resources, wicket

Wicket automatically generates URLs to resources (images etc.) with the prefix "resources" (e.g. "http://localhost:8080/resources/org.apache.wicket.ajax.WicketAjaxReference/wicket-ajax.js"). Is it possible to change this prefix from "resources" to something else (like "res")?

I have another servlet providing stuff under "resources" and I cannot change it (don't ask...), hence I would like Wicket to serve its resources with a different prefix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in Wicket 1.4, since the path is defined as the constant `org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.request.WebRequestCodingStrategy.RESOURCES_PATH_PREFIX` and is used hardcoded in the Wicket filter.

In Wicket 1.5 it seems you have to override `org.apache.wicket.Application.getEncoderContext()` with an `IMapperContext` which returns your new prefix in `getResourceIdentifier()`.

Comment: In Wicket 6 this has become `newMapperContext`